# Session is Invalid Error in Spring Boot Using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http, undertow

I am using undertow server , undertow servlet 2.2.9.FINAL

The code is to authenticate Rest Api Endpoints and Servlet Endpoint

Can you please suggest how to fix this Issue?

I am not getting any error in Dev and UAT Environment, but getting error in Production Environment intermitently.

I was expecting servlet and rest api to work fine.
But I am getting intermittent issue of Session is invalid.
Another service is hitting end point with token, token is valid still getting issue.
There is no issue in Servlet. which is accessd from browser

Comment: @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Configure security for servlet endpoints
        http
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().
            .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
             .antMatchers("/servlet-endpoint/**").authenticated()
             .anyRequest().permitAll().and()
             .addFilterBefore(customFilter,SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter);
            .csrf().disabled();

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException : Session is invalid -YDJDFSBSDNFSJVSHGSGNS
InMemorySessionManager. ..undertow-core 2.2.17.FINAl.jar
SavedRequest.java ........undertow-servlet
CacheAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java